# Erlang code explained

Tags: erlang

I am having a bit of trouble getting my head around the following erlang code

```
-module(threesix).  
-export([quicksort/1]).  

quicksort(Pivot, Left, Right, []=_Src) ->  
     {Left, Pivot, Right};  
quicksort(Pivot, Left, Right, [H|T]=_Src) when H < Pivot ->  
     quicksort(Pivot, [H|Left], Right, T);  
quicksort(Pivot, Left, Right, [H|T]=_Src) ->  
     quicksort(Pivot, Left, [H|Right], T).  

quicksort([]) ->  
     [];  
quicksort([H|T]=_List) ->  
     {Left, Pivot, Right} = quicksort(H, [], [], T),  
     quicksort(Left) ++ [Pivot] ++ quicksort(Right).
```

I am specifically talking about the use of _Src and _List in the parameters.

Are these simply for documentation as I cannot see why they are used?

Comment: As sepp2k said they aren't used, these are anonymous (don't care) variables and thus you could omit them.

Comment: @Yasir, that isn't completely correct, the _ at the beginning of a variable name just tells the compiler to supress the unused variable warning for that variable. it is still a regular variable and can be used, but probably shouldn't be unless the _ is removed. If you really don't care about them and will never use them then just use _ . There is really interesting recent thread about this on the mailing list [http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.erlang.general/43491/focus=43499]

Comment: It is important to distinguish between the variable `_` which **is** the don't care variable and variables which start with a `_` which are actually normal variables and can be used as such. The compiler will just not warn if they are not used and some people use them to "comment" their code. As the link @fuzzy gives shows I don't like that and never use them as such.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, they're only for documentation. They're not actually used (as signified by the leading underscore).

Comment: actually there is nothing to enforce them "not actually used" the _ just tells the compiler not to complain about them not being used.

Comment: @fuzzylollipop: Right, but by putting the _ there you're basically saying "I don't intend to use this variable - I only named it for clarity"